# Better file format for pdf generation

Tags: perl

can anybody please tell me what kind of intermediate file formats are available for converting an input file into a PDF ? 
Brief Note: I have the data in the format of XML'S. These xmls should be mapped into an intermediate file which is then used to generate a pdf.

Comment: There's Apache FOP: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

Comment: docbook xml, simple docbook.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly create a PDF from XML using [PDF::API2](http://search.cpan.org/~ssimms/PDF-API2-2.020/lib/PDF/API2.pm) or [PDF::Create](http://search.cpan.org/~szabgab/PDF-Create-1.08/lib/PDF/Create.pm)

Example:

```
  use PDF::Create;
  # initialize PDF
  my $pdf = PDF::Create->new('filename'     => 'mypdf.pdf',
                                        'Author'       => 'John Doe',
                                        'Title'        => 'Sample PDF',
                                        'CreationDate' => [ localtime ], );

  # add a A4 sized page
  my $a4 = $pdf->new_page('MediaBox' => $pdf->get_page_size('A4'));

  # Add a page which inherits its attributes from $a4
  my $page = $a4->new_page;

  # Prepare a font
  my $f1 = $pdf->font('BaseFont' => 'Helvetica');

  # Prepare a Table of Content
  my $toc = $pdf->new_outline('Title' => 'Title Page', 'Destination' => $page);

  # Write some text
  $page->stringc($f1, 40, 306, 426, "PDF::Create");
  $page->stringc($f1, 20, 306, 396, "version $PDF::Create::VERSION");
  $page->stringc($f1, 20, 306, 300, 'by John Doe <john.doe@example.com>');
  #close
  $pdf->close();
```